# Fungivore that feeds specifically on spores

Tags: zoology, mycology

I'm wondering if anyone has knowledge of an organism that specifically feeds on the spores of fungi. When I attempt to research this the results are flooded with numerous examples of fungivores but I've never been able to locate any information specifically on spore consumption.

Perhaps no organisms are known to feed directly on spores but I find this surprising. It seems spores would be an excellent and abundant nutrient source for a properly adapted organism.

Answer (score 12):

This paper:

> Smelansky, I.E., 2006. Some population characteristics of oribatid mites in steppe habitats. *Acarina*, 14(1), pp.123-130.

includes analysis of the gut content of some mites, recognizing several trophic guilds including "specialized
sporovores, and (specialized) sporovores ‘feeding
on surface’ ".  These two guilds are described:

> specialized
> sporovores feed on a very limited set of fungal
> spores including only 4–5 morphological kinds of
> spores in each mite species; the guts of sporovores ‘feeding on surface’ contain unusually high portion
> of pollen grains and spores of epiphytic fungi.